# How can I display the maximum or all key lengths that openssl can use on my system for rsa or others with bash in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

My system:

```
Linux 5.10.0-22-amd64|Debian 5.10.178-3|x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
```

With this i see all `public-key-algorithms` supported on my system

```
openssl list -public-key-algorithms
```

```
Name: OpenSSL RSA method
        Type: Builtin Algorithm
        OID: rsaEncryption
        PEM string: RSA
Name: rsa
        Alias for: rsaEncryption
Name: OpenSSL PKCS#3 DH method
        Type: Builtin Algorithm
        OID: dhKeyAgreement
        PEM string: DH
.......
.......
.......
```

Now i want a list of all or the max key length that are available on my system for `rsa` or others in bash.

The commands are from the internet

None of these commands work:

```
openssl rsa -h | grep "rsa\\(-.*\\)\\?\\[num\\]"

openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm RSA -list_all

openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm RSA -text

openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm RSA -out rsa.param

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -list-public -noout

openssl genpkey -genparam -algorithm RSA -out /dev/null -text

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -list_keyalg

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -listpubout | openssl rsa -text -noout | grep "Private-Key:"
```

I either get this

> genpkey: Unrecognized flag list-public
> genpkey: Use -help for summary.

or that error

> Error initializing RSA context
> 140003190199616:error:06095096:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_paramgen_init:operation not supported for this keytype:../crypto/evp/pmeth_gn.c:23:

How can i list all or the `max-key-length` that are available on my system for `rsa` or others in bash.

Comment: I think it is irrelevant to ask for list of available RSA key lengths. Key lengths are usually power of 2 but there is not a technical limitation to have any key length. Usage key length does not fit to byte/register/cache-line/page boundaries may cause a performance penalty but they can be used. Openssl can generate very long RSA keys but generation long keys are CPU demanding.